# WebFrame loadData not working?

Tags: html, objective-c, macos, webview

I'm trying to make a WebView load a page from HTML code I have stored as an NSData. I get a blank page when I try to do this. Is there anything wrong with what I'm doing when I load the page? If not, I need to look elsewhere in my program.

```
if (essence.html){ //essence.html is an NSData
    NSLog(@"Inserting HTML code into browser window: %@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:essence.html encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
    [webView.mainFrame loadData:essence.html MIMEType: @"text/html" textEncodingName: @"utf-8" baseURL:nil]; //webView is a WebView
}
```

I created the conditions so essence.html contains HTML code from the page http://kathleenmelian.com/test.html (which just says "hello"). The NSLog prints this when the above code runs:

```
Inserting HTML code into browser window: <html><head></head><body>hello</body></html>
```

So essence.html definitely contains valid code that a browser should be able to load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry to bother you guys. I fixed some other bug in my program's model, and that somehow fixed THIS problem as well. I don't know how. Crisis averted.

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
[webView loadHTMLString:
   [[NSString alloc] initWithData:essence.html encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
   baseURL:nil];
```

The other idea would be to replace `"utf-8"` with `"UTF-8"`, which in some cases is known to make a difference (not sure about UIWebView).

Comment: Thanks, but it's still not showing up. It actually has to be webView.mainFrame since mainFrame returns the WebFrame of the WebView, and that's what has the load methods. WebView is different from UIWebView (used in iOS) in this way. I've tried "UTF-8" too, but there is no difference. Apple documentation says to use "utf-8".

Comment: In iOS, `UIWebView` does not have a `mainFrame` property. Sorry, you are probably mixing up SDKs.

Comment: I'm in OS X. I'm kinda annoyed that Apple made a UIWebView and a WebView that are different things :/